# glReadPixel (One Pass vs Looping Through Points)

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm pretty new to OpenGL and C++ and have recently been trying to extract depth values from a window I've rendered. I've noticed something funny, and I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

If I call glReadPixel with "width" and "height" values matching my window size, I get a certain depth map.

However, if I loop through the pixels individually, calling glReadPixel at each point, I get a different depth map. The one I get by doing this is the "correct" one, or at least the depth map I would expect. The one I get by grabbing all the depth values in "one-pass," so to speak, is a horizontally stretched out version of the second.

Here's the essential code I'm using for the "one-pass" method, with a small subsample of my window (10x5 block)

```
int size = window_height * window_width;
depth_ = new GLfloat[size];
glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);
glReadPixels(0, 0, 10, 5, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, depth_);
// left to right, bottom to top
int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            myfile << i << " " << j << " " << depth_[count] << std::endl;
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Here's the code I used by looping through each point, and calling glReadPixel individually for each pixel:

```
glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);
float depthPixel;
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        glReadPixels(i, j, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &depthPixel);
        myfile << i << " " << j << " " << depthPixel << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The first few values of text file I save from the "one-pass" method looks like this:

```
0 0 0.462552  (1)
1 0 0.463212  
2 0 0.463831  (2)
3 0 0.464458  
4 0 0.46518   (3)
5 0 0.465858  
6 0 0.466519  (4)
```

While the second, looping method looks like this:

```
0 0 0.462552  (1)
1 0 0.463831  (2)
2 0 0.46518   (3)
3 0 0.466519  (4)
4 0 0.467764
5 0 0.469067
6 0 0.47047
```

As you can see, an extra depth value is inserted between each point in the first example, almost as if I'm sampling at twice the rate.

Once again, I'm new to OpenGL and a lot of this stuff, so it's possible that I'm making a very stupid, beginner mistake. Nonetheless, I haven't been able to figure it out on my own.

Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Which version of OpenGL are you using, on what graphics hardware?

Comment: (One reason I ask is, I note users of retina displays report some oddities: e.g the remarkably similar http://forum.jogamp.org/Problem-with-glReadPixels-on-OS-X-retina-display-td4033426.html )

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might reside here:

```
int size = window_height * window_width;
…
glReadPixels(0, 0, 10, 5, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, depth_);
                    ^^^^^
                         \--- ?!?!
```

You have some width=10, height=5 values hardcoded there, which will of course not make OpenGL properly fill your buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone, I've discovered what was wrong after hunting around to see if my Retina display was causing the problem.

When I had initialized my window, I had multi-sampling turned on like this:

```
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
```

I set it back to default, and then added some code afterwards to account for my Retina display (scale down to match the actual window width/height I wanted.)

```
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 0);
```

This fixed my problem. I'm still not entirely sure what was going on with the double sampling in the horizontal direction only, but I'm guessing it has something to do with the multi-sampling I had inherited from some sample code online, and maybe it interacting with the Retina display.

Anyway, your comments helped me look in the right direction, and everything is working as I expect now.